# Decompressing XML file with unknown compression method

Tags: decompress

Would there be anyway at all to determine the compression method used for this XML file given only the compressed XML?

I've looked into different XML compression methods such as EXI, but can't seem to be able to decode this.

It's a vehicle XML file from the game stormworks, they recently updated the game so dedicated servers compress vehicle files to save storage space and for faster file transfer times between the server and clients. We had planned to create a sub-system of our server management program that parsed the blocks used in the vehicle to determine what blocks and how many were used.

Here is the compressed XML in plain text: https://pastebin.com/zSg7DrF3 and on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yufpcxxx8utuo57/vehicle.bin?dl=0

Thanks

Comment: Might be impossible to deduce without looking at the executable that is compressing/decompressing it.

Comment: @morsisko It is for the game called stormworks on steam

Comment: Unfortunately there is very little chance someone will do all the work for you for free. Even worse you need to pay for this game, so in case someone wants to help you, they need not only invest their time but also their money. You see how it looks.